# How to output JavaScript results into an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i'm trying to make it so when I press submit, it spits out the results of the first box, and outputs it as processed Javascript into the iframe, for some reason the box disappears on the webpage whenever I press the button.

```js
    function resetAreaBox(){
        $('display').value = "";
        $('textarea1').value = "";
    }

    function $(id){ return document.getElementById(id)}

function check() {

   var box = $("textarea1");

    if (box.value) {
       

        $("display").innerHTML = box.value;
        
    } else {
        alert('Please enter text');
    }
}
$("button").onclick = check;
```

```html
<form>
                    <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="TEST"></textarea>

                    <iframe id="display"></iframe>


                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" id="submitAlert" value="Reset Field" onclick="resetAreaBox()">
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="button">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSBin - http://jsbin.com/midexefiqo/1/edit?html,js,output

There was many errors in your code. I fixed them.

You can't just add `iframe` in HTML and play with it. See the JS code.

On submit, it will call a function `displayPreview` in your `if` condition and preview.